# Reproduce values from an original array after substitution of each element with the mean value of its neighbours in C

Tags: c, loops, mean

I have substituted the values in an array with the values of the arithmetic mean of its neighbours in C:

```
int main(void) {
int tab[5] = {1,2,4,6,8};

for (int i = 1; i<4; i++) {
tab[i] = (tab[i-1]+tab[i+1])/2;
}
return 0;
}
```

I have excluded the first and the last element. Then, I want to reproduce the orginal values in the modified array. I have tried:

```
for (int i = 3; i>=1; i--) {
    tab[i-1] = 2*tab[i] - tab[i+1];
}
```

but it doesn't work. **How to reproduce the original values?** I want to modify the original list in order to avoid the memory usage for initialization of the new array.

Comment: Unless you have identified a very specific memory constraint in your problem domain that you must adhere to, it's almost certainly going to be better to use two arrays.  Using a single array makes the logic difficult to follow, and I'm not sure it's even possible to unravel it this way.

Comment: For starters, how do you distinguish between 1, 4, 7 and 2, 4, 6?

Comment: Fun fact: the initial second value in array is irrelevant. It's just overwritten. Ergo it's not possible to recover all original values. Also even/odd sum will give the same number.

Comment: It's not possible. By setting, say the element at index 1, to the average of element at index 0 and 2 you are effectively losing the data at index 1. It could be anything but it would be set to the same value, which is the average of it's neighbors. The modifications to following elements depend on the new value. Hence, you cannot retrieve the original value at index 1 and by extension the value of any following element.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that IN THIS CASE.

**Also there are hidden mistake in your code (explained at bottom)**

look at the modified array in your case

```
arr[0] = 1 //unmodified in loop
arr[1] = 2 //(5/2 = 2) in int data type
arr[2] = 4 //(arr[1]+6)/2 = (2+6)/2 = 4
arr[3] = 6 //(arr[2]+8)/2 = (4+8)/2 = 6
arr[4] = 8 //unmodified
```

since, its a specific case where the modified array is same, so some of the mistakes would be hidden.
but what happens when your second loop has i=1

```
arr[i-1]=2*arr[i] - arr[i+1]
arr[0]=2*arr[1] - arr[2]
```

taking values from above

```
arr[0] = 0 // which is different from original arr[0]
```

**If you want to just examine this use `float` instead of `int` as data type of array and see what happens.**

**also try putting an even value in the first element while using the `int` data type.**

Now, the mistakes

1. you said you want to replace elements with avg of their neighbours. but (not in this special case where original elements are retained) what happens is the loop works correctly only 1st time and from 2nd run it is taking a value `tab[i-1]` which you modified in the previous loop run.
2. same is the case of your second de-modification loop, from 2nd run onwards, it takes a value `tab[i+1]` that you modified in previous run.
3. even if everything else works,
   do you realize that in second loop, you are assigning original values from 2nd to 0th positions instead of their original 3rd to 1st.